# how to get jenkins jobs list using groovy script in script consol

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am running following script

```
import hudson.plugins.emailext.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.maven.*
import hudson.maven.reporters.*
import hudson.tasks.*

def jobNames = "${jobs}";
jobNames = jobNames.split(",");

println("Jobs:       " + jobNames);
println();
```

it is failing with exception which is follow:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jobs for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
```

Comment: ${jobs} is never defined ...

Answer (score 0):

> how to get jenkins jobs list using groovy script in script console

Collection of all jobs:

```
Jenkins.instance.items
```

Print full name of each job on a line:

```
Jenkins.instance.items*.fullName.join('\n')
```